# In smartphones which is more expenisve to implement ? 'Optical Image Stabilisation' or 'In Body Image Stabilization'?

Tags: image-stabilization

As the title implies, I am asking what is more expensive to put into smartphone cameras- OIS or IBIS?

Almost all phones on the market use OIS. However, the recent iPhones (12 Pro Max and 13 lineup) have IBIS- which Apple has dubbed 'Sensor-Shift Stabilisation'.

So I was wondering if IBIS is more expensive to implement than OIS.
Is it ?

PS: I am aware that there are questions that ask which is cheaper OIS or IBIS. However unlike those questions, my question is regarding stabilization on smartphone cameras, not dedicated/normal cameras.

Comment: While you are correct that your question is nominally different, the answer is the same: it depends. I don't see much value in having another question to which the answer is just that again, so I'm closing this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed with Philip: this question duplicates the more generic question. Cost to implement is very time-dependent, and forward-looking (i.e., projective, or speculative) from the manufacturers' perspectives.